# Textarea wont act right on blur

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with my textarea on focus and blur. What its suppose to do is take two variables "textField" and "textDefault". textDefault holds the content that the textarea has when the page is loaded. I added this into a variable because i needed to compare the current contents to the original contents.

I take the .html() of the textarea, and if it equals the text in the textDefault, i do $(this).html("") to remove the inner html. Then on blur i do the opposite. I check to see if the textField is equal to "" and if it does, to put textDefault's value back into the textarea with $(this).html(textDefault).

The problem im having is that it works fine and dandy with clicking on and off the textarea, but if you enter data into the textarea, then backspace all the way, it doesnt put the original data back into the textarea.

Any suggestions? Heres the code:

PS: I forgot to mention, that in there i set the height to auto on focus, to make the textarea the height of the content, then i set the height to 190 on blur. Just fyi This is so the textarea isnt 100 feet tall when you may only type 2 words.

```
var textField;
var textDefault = "Click the title to add a title for this admin dashboard panel. Click     here to add a body. This body can contain html, or regular text.\n\nIt can be used for admin notes mainly, but to communicate with other admins as well.\n\nContact the developer of this website (max@haintmorgan.com) to have this widget actually contain php driven content.";

$('.admin-note-body textarea').focus(function(){
    textField = $(this).html();

    if(textField == textDefault){
        $(this).html("");
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if($('.admin-note-body textarea').html() == ""){
        $('.admin-note-body textarea').html(textDefault);
        $(this).css('height', '190px');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="" cols="">Click the title to add a title for this admin dashboard panel. Click here to add a body. This body can contain html, or regular text.

It can be used for admin notes mainly, but to communicate with other admins as well.

Contact the developer of this website (max@haintmorgan.com) to have this widget actually contain php driven content.</textarea>
```

For sake of saving you time,

Click the title to add a title for this admin dashboard panel. Click here to add a body. This body can contain html, or regular text.\n\nIt can be used for admin notes mainly, but to communicate with other admins as well.\n\nContact the developer of this website (max@haintmorgan.com) to have this widget actually contain php driven content.

This is the contents of textDefault. It does the same content on three lines (notice the \n\n) on the html without \n\n. \n is done twice because there is a line break seperating each mini paragraph..

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
David

PSS: Note the height to 190px works but the html doesnt. I notice doing console.log on everything that textField and .html() and textDefault all hold hte same value no matter what.

Comment: You should use `.val()` instead of `.html()` to access the contents of a textarea.

Comment: TheifMaster.. Youre a genius. Thanks sooooooo much!

Comment: Posted it as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()` not `.html()`

Also you can clean up your code by making better use of `$(this)`:

```
$('.admin-note-body textarea').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == textDefault){
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).css('height', '190px');
    }
});
```

Also the `placeholder` attribute in HTML5 does this without the need for Javascript:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: Thanks alex as well. TheifMaster said the same above and it worked! Thank you both.. And i wanted to avoid using HTML 5..

Comment: Even if you don't use HTML5 - you can (and should!) still use it unless you really want validators to like your HTML code. For browsers not supporting it, it's super-easy to add this functionality using JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: use `.val()` instead of `.html()` to access the contents of a textarea.